# Why Open AI + .Net Framework 4.8 not working?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, openai-api, .net-4.8

I have an issue with working with Open AI API in .NET 4.8.

I have a code that works ok in .NET 8, unfortunatelly I must use .NET 4.8 and it don't work. Between versions 8.0 and 4.8 there is only a little difference when it comes to handling json (de)serialization. Commented code is used in 8.0

```
        private static async Task Request()
    {
        string Result;
        string APIK_KEY = "some api key";
        string someLongText = @"long text";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", APIK_KEY);

        var request = new OpenAIRequest
        {
            Model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            Temperature = 0.7f,
            MaxTokens = 200,
            Messages = new List<Message>()
{
    new Message() { Role = "system", Content = "You are a helpful assistant." },
    new Message() { Role = "user", Content = "Please concise below text: " +someLongText }
}
        };
        var json = Serialize.SerializeJson<OpenAIRequest>(request);   // JsonSerializer.Serialize(new JsonTextWriter(), request);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        var resjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var errorResponse = Serialize.DeserializeJson<OpenAIErrorResponse>(resjson);// JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OpenAIErrorResponse>(resjson);
            throw new System.Exception(errorResponse.Error.Message);
        }
        //var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OpenAIResponse>(resjson);
        var data = Serialize.DeserializeJson<Root>(resjson); //JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(resjson);
        //var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(resjson, typeof(object));
        Result = data.Choices[0].Message.Content;

        Console.WriteLine(Result);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return;
    }
}
```

How to make it work in .NET 4.8? When line

```
                response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);
```

is reached, the app just stops and gives no error.

EDIT: thanks for hints about async stuff, I've changed the code to await that async function and now it gives error.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at A_Add_in.OpenAIServices.<SendPrompt>d__9.MoveNext() in C[...]:line 151
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at A_Add_in.Models.OpenAIModel.<GetAIResponse>d__4.MoveNext() in C[...]:line 31

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The thing is... I can complete that code in .NET 4.8 console app (I've just created it and run), but in .NET 4.8 VSTO add-in it gives me this error. I've tried several solutions (like adding key to registry) that I've found on internet, but with no success.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions listed in the Debugger Output window?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }`  <-- Don't do this. Only catch the exceptions you expect to be thrown (e.g. `JsonException` and/or `HttpRequestException`) and **never** do `throw e;` because that drops the stack-trace, so do `throw;` (the keyword by itself); and only `catch` if you intend to _do something_ with the exception, such as logging - and be sure to re-throw exceptions you cannot gracefully handle.

Comment: "just stops and gives no error" suggests to me an async deadlock. Show us how yo are calling the `Request` method - are you using `Task.Result` by any chance?

Comment: why do you need to use .NET 4.8? If it's about libraries then .NET Core already has the ability to build a single static exe file output

Comment: @phuclv VSTO solution/PowerPoint add-in - Microsoft does not support it in .NET Core

Comment: The API [supports only TLS versions 1.2 and 1.3](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.openai.com). Could you let us know what version of Windows you're using? .NET Framework will support TLS versions 1.2 and 1.3 so long as the OS supports it.

Comment: Win 10 Enteprise, build 19045. I've updated the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I have added that line of code:

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

and it started working :)

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -2):

As DavidG suggested in their comment, since we don't have detail on how you called this async method or the exception contents, the exception got (unexpectedly) silently thrown in another thread and ignored seems most possible.

Fix the async calling, use debugger to set a breakpoint, or at least add Console.WriteLine to see the exception contents. If there is no exception at all - that means issue lies somewhere else, which we'd need more detail to look into -, debugger can also help you trying to narrow down where the stopping point exactly is.

```cs
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f); // add a logging here to see exception details
            throw f; // or set debugger here
        }
```